# value of type 'Scanner' has no member 'scanHexInt32'

Tags: macos, swift3, ubuntu-16.04, perfect

When I compile my Swift project for Mac it compiles fine but when I compile same code in Ubuntu 16.04 I get following error.

```
value of type 'Scanner' has no member 'scanHexInt32'
        if Scanner(string: self).scanHexInt32(&value) {
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Foundation.Scanner:8:17: note: did you mean 'scanHexInt'?
    public func scanHexInt(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> Bool
```

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

it needs different flags:

```
    import Foundation

    public extension String {
      public func scanHex() -> UInt32? {
        var value = UInt32(0)
        #if os(Linux)
        if Scanner(string: self).scanHexInt(&value) {
          return value
        } else {
          return nil
        }
        #else
        if Scanner(string: self).scanHexInt32(&value) {
          return value
        } else {
          return nil
        }
        #endif
      }
    }

    if let x = "0x100".scanHex() {
      print("scanned:", x)
    } else {
      print("scan failed")
    }
```

This main.swift was tested on both mac / linux.